# Xamarin Live Player - The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-live-player

Just testing out the Xamarin Live Player which sounds awesome but for the life of me, I can't get it to play ball.

I've set it all up as the steps on their website says then just created a brand new template cross-platform master details application with Xamarin Forms. When I've paired up the device and run it I receive errors saying "The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found.

I've done nothing different to the template project and when I run it to a device or the simulator it runs fine. I've run through their troubleshooting tips and gotten nowhere.

Any advice?

Comment: refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105818/net-standart-live-player-xamarin-forms  , it seems to work on android but not ios ,you can test it via Test Flight for the alternative.

Comment: FYI: In a **Android** device, it doesn't throw any errors, but in order to see any simple XAML changes, _"Live"_, had to repeat the process of re-capturing the QR code (with the camera) and re-pairing the device again every time. Not good.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. I'm mainly concerned about getting it playing ball on an iOS device at this point which is where i've tested it so far and hit these problems.

Comment: Did you try to use it with [these](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/samples/). These are sample apps that should work with live player. Live player is buggy, especially for ios. I recommend to use Test flight version of the app.

Comment: @Matt sometimes this happens if the project name is too long, try with a shorter one, could be what's causing this.

Comment: Do you get the error "The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found" even when building on a device? I would try to remove the reference to Xamarin.Forms in every project and re-add it!

Comment: I tried the above suggestion to remove and re-add the references with no success. I lodged a support case with Xamarin (Microsoft support) and they have replicated the issue and have lodged an issue in their system and i am waiting for them to provide a work around/patch fix if they are able to.